# Not enough space to install Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, ubuntu

I'm using Pop OS 20.4 and installed Unity Hub from its store (I think it just downloads the app image from the Unity website and installs it but I don't know).

I set a personal license and want to install the version 2020.1.15f1. As you can see on the next tab there is enough space to install it

[image]

Unfortunately I get this error message when trying to install it

[image]

at the bottom of the hub this toast message appears

[image]

Does someone know what's wrong here? I clearly have enough space on my disk.

[image]

I get the same error for other versions too.

Comment: It suggest you dont have 17.5gb free where it wants it

Comment: but I have enough space as you can see in the image

Comment: Do you have multiple partitions? Some stuff has to go to the main partition sometimes so maybe you don't have enough space on another partition?

Answer (score 1):

Ok here is the solution that worked for me:

Instead of installing it from the Pop OS store I uninstalled this Unity hub version. I restarted my machine and installed the .appimage file from the official website. I copied that file into the root of my home directory. When executing this version there was no error for me.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why it is showing this error is because there is not enough space in your root directory. Typically this happens when there is only a single partition (at least in my case). So a workaround for this is to create a folder in you HOME directory called tmp and running the UnityHub.AppImage file pointing to that tmp folder and the application gets ample amount of space to install. It looks something like this :

TEMP=~/tmp ./UnityHub.AppImage

You can go to this [link](https://www.reddit.com/r/Unity3D/comments/f6h2y1/linux_unity_hub_not_enough_space/) for further details.